# MULE: How to use CDATA in MEL

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mel, mule-el

Please help me on this error.I have captured original payload  through session variable in mainflow.In case of error scenario's, I have another subflow, where i have used `Message Property Transformer` and `XSLT transformer`. So when i try to put  wrongly formatted xml( trying to create parser exception).In XSLT transformer throwing error like "Element type "messageNamestr1234" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>" ".

Actually my logic is, in error scenario's i supposed to construct the xml - in that one of the filed need to capture `original payload`.In all other testing scenario it seems to be working fine( properly xml is generated). But only for parser exception, messages is not propagating in to the queue since XSLT throwing error. Please find my config xml

```
        <flow name="mainFlow" doc:name="MessageFlow"
    tracking:enable-default-events="true">

    <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="InQUEUE"
        tracking:enable-default-events="true" connector-ref="WMQ_Connector"
        doc:name="queue" doc:description="Flow">
        <wmq:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
    </wmq:inbound-endpoint>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Store_Payload"/> 
    <logger message="***change*#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.Object)]*****" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer></mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer>
              <set-session-variable variableName="operation"
        value="#[xpath('fn:local-name(/root/*[2])')]" doc:name="Set_Operation" doc:description="separate Operation"/>       
    ..........
    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy" doc:description="used to differenciate system and application error">
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch_ApplicationFailure_Messages"
            when="#[exception.causedBy(org.mule.api.MessagingException)]" doc:description="Catches all the application errors and call the error handling subflow to log the error messages">
            <flow-ref name="Common_ErrorHandling_SubFlow" doc:name="Invoke_Common_ErrorHandling_SubFlow" />
        </catch-exception-strategy>

        <rollback-exception-strategy
            maxRedeliveryAttempts="3" doc:name="Catch_SystemFailure_Messages" doc:description="Message Processor catches system error and tries to retry for 3 times and finally put the message in queue"> 
        ................        
        </rollback-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
</flow>

     <sub-flow name="Common_ErrorHandling_SubFlow" doc:name="Common_ErrorHandling_SubFlow"
    tracking:enable-default-events="true">

    <logger message="***enetered**" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    <message-properties-transformer
        doc:name="Catch_MessageProperties" doc:description="Used to capture project and message specific information" scope="outbound">

        <add-message-property key="InterfaceName" value="'Requests'" />
        <add-message-property key="ProjectName" value="'NewProject'" />
        ..........
        <add-message-property key="JMSMessageID"
            value="#[header:INBOUND:JMSMessageID]" />
        <add-message-property key="MuleMessageID"
            value="#[header:INBOUND:MULE_MESSAGE_ID]" />
        <add-message-property key="ExceptionPayload"
            value="#[exception]" />
        <add-message-property key="originalPayload" value="#[sessionVars.originalPayload]"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>

    <mulexml:xslt-transformer
        maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5"
        doc:name="Generate_ErrorXmlStructure" xsl-file="XSLTScript.txt" doc:description="XSLT transformer used to generate standard xml message with its scripts">
        <mulexml:xslt-text>
        </mulexml:xslt-text>

        <mulexml:context-property key="ProjectName"
            value="#[header:OUTBOUND:ProjectName]" />
        .........
        <mulexml:context-property key="DetailsExceptionMessage"
            value="#[header:OUTBOUND:DetailsExceptionMessage]" />
        <mulexml:context-property key="OriginalPayload"
            value="#[header:OUTBOUND:originalPayload]" />
        <mulexml:context-property key="MessageInDate"
            value="#[header:OUTBOUND:MessageInDate]" />
        <mulexml:context-property key="InputQueue"
            value="#[header:OUTBOUND:InputQueue]" />
    </mulexml:xslt-transformer>

    <wmq:outbound-endpoint queue="ERROR"
        connector-ref="WMQ_Connector" doc:name=".ERROR" doc:description="Used to log error messages">
        <wmq:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/>
    </wmq:outbound-endpoint>
</sub-flow>
```

Assumption:since it is parser exception, XSLT Transformer excepting standard xml structure (in capturing payload). So thought to route in CDATA.Not sure how to do it.Also tried various options in context properties in XSLT transformer

```
       1. <mulexml:context-property key="OriginalPayload"
            value="#[message.outboundproperies.originalPayloadAs(java.lang.Object)]" /> 
       2.<mulexml:context-property key="OriginalPayload"
            value="#[header:SESSION:originalPayload]" />
       3.<mulexml:context-property key="OriginalPayload"
            value="#[!CDATA[sessionVars.originalPayload]]" />
```

but no hope.Kindly help me on this.

@DavidDossot: I have added my XLST scipt and i changed the parameters as you suggested.

```
      <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" cdata-section-elements="OriginalPayload" />
                    <xsl:param name="InterfaceName" />
                    <xsl:param name="ProjectName" />
                       ..........
                    <xsl:param name="OriginalPayload" />
                    <xsl:param name="MessageInDate" />
                    <xsl:template match="*">
                        <Specific>
                            <ProjectName>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$ProjectName" />
                            </ProjectName>
                            <InterfaceName>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$InterfaceName" />
                            </InterfaceName>
                                .......
                           <OriginalPayload>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$OriginalPayload"/>
                        </OriginalPayload> 
                 </Specific>
                    </xsl:template>
                </xsl:stylesheet>
```

also in Context properties i have added

```
                    <mulexml:context-property key="OriginalPayload"
            value="#[sessionVars.originalPayload]" />
```

Still i'm facing the same error. I have tried multiple options 1.Removed omit-xml-declaration 2.Edited many properties in xslt and tried. No hope. Kindly guide me where i have gone wrong.

@DavidDossot please find my input xml ( removed > from messageName filed to check parser exception behaviour in flow)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <root>
   <header>
   <messageName>str1234</messageName>
   <messageId>12345</messageId>
   <storeNo>123</storeNo>
   <storeElement>str1</storeElement>
   <requestDateTime>2012-12-13T12:12:12</requestDateTime>
   </header>
   <Request>
   <messageNamestr1234</messageName>
   </Request>
   </root>
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the original payload is a string, you should be able to pass it to the XSL-T directly with:

```
<mulexml:context-property key="OriginalPayload"
        value="#[sessionVars.originalPayload]" />
```

Then in your [XSL `output` configuration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output), put the name of the XML element that will contain the original payload in `cdata-section-elements`:

```
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="yourElementNameHere"/>
```

PS. `header:OUTBOUND` is deprecated use `message.outboundProperties`.

Comment: Hi @David Dossot - Thank you. I have changed the properties as you suggested. Still facing the same problem. I have edited above config and added the XLST script. Kindly have a glance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried the above XSL and it works perfectly fine: `OriginalPayload` is wrapped in a CDATA block. You must have other issues at play, but as far as XSL is concerned, my solution works.

Comment: Thank You @DavidDossot. yes we can able to wrap the payload in CDATA. But the problem occurs only if we are  trying for parser error message. We are getting error like `lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 24; Element type "messageNamestr1234" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"`. It works fine for all other exception except parser exception. As soon as message entered in to XSLT transformer, it is throwing the error. I have edited above config and given input xml. Please have a glance.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap the original payload in CDATA via MEL when we are storing it in session var itself.

Comment: No: CDATA is purely an XML serialization concern, nothing you can do at MEL level. I can't find in your question the XSL-T error you are receiving: can you add it? Also, are you sure that all the `context-property` values you are passing to your XSL are strings?

Comment: Thank you @DavidDossort for you constant support. Not only for this, to my most of the questions. Your answers helped me to improved alot in dev activities. Finally found the error. Actually XSLT transformer is expecting the well formed xml. Since i'm doing testing for the parser error, in my common error handling subflow incoming payload is not well formed xml (input). That is the reason xslt throwing the error. Used SetPayload temporary in subflow and override the existing wrong xml with dummy correct xml. Now able to put the messages in queue for parser exception also.